# Azure CLI to open ports

Tags: linux, command-line, port, azure

I'm following the following to use Azure CLI to open ports
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/nsg-quickstart

I.e., the command,

```
az vm open-port --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM --port 80
```

works fine. However, when I try to open up the next port, 21, I got this:

```
Security rule open-port-80 conflicts with rule open-port-21. Rules cannot have the same Priority and Direction.
```

So

- how do I open a bunch of ports (not just one) to my VM using Azure CLI?
- how do I add more ports to the already opened set of ports to my VM using Azure CLI?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your issue, you want to open port for your Azure VM. Actually, they're Network Security Group(NSG) rules. You used command:

`az vm open-port --resourcr-group myResourceGroup --name myVM --port 80`

It used the default priority and it's just one.

So you can use special and complete command to create rules. And the rules like this:

`az network nsg rule create --name myRuleName --resource-group myResourveGroup --priority 100 --access Allow --source-address-prefixes '*' --source-port-ranges '*' --destination-address-prefixes '*' --destination-port-ranges 80 --protocol Tcp`

For more detail about the command you can read [az network nsg rule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#commands).

Comment: If the answer helpful please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This example worked as of Aug 12 2018 to allow tcp/2222 inbound

`az network nsg rule create --nsg-name c3nsg --resource-group c3 -n c3nsg-nonstandard-ssh --direction Inbound --priority 101 --access Allow --source-address-prefixes * --source-port-ranges * --destination-address-prefixes * --destination-port-ranges 2222 --protocol tcp`