# Azure CLI to list opened ports

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Following up on [Azure CLI to open ports](https://superuser.com/questions/1330240/), now, is there any Azure CLI command that can show/list what the open ports are of a VM?

Thanks

Comment: You already know from the other answer that this is not really about "open ports" (which can also mean "applications listening on such a port"), but about network security rules (which *allow* connections to particular ports, to and from particular machines etc.). So have you looked at the `az network nsg` command? In particular e.g. `az network nsg --help`? The `--help` option really helps...

Comment: Thanks for your lecture @dirkt, Is your lecture really necessary than just providing with the answer? One simply `az network nsg -h` is better than your lecture. Moreover, `az network nsg` can output some long texts that contain opened ports, but you think that's enough do you? How about give a list of opened ports for the inquired VM? That's what I'm really asking for.